# implement jwt client in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, jwt, refresh-token

I want to implement jwt client in RN. Getting new token works properly but when token expired and I want to refresh token it does not work.This is my Get function code:

```
let result = await instance
  .get(url)
  .then(({data}) => {
    if (data.error) {
      return {data: data.message, error: true, redirect: false};
    }
  return {data: data.data, error: false, redirect: false};
  })
  .catch(err => {
    if (err.response.status === 401) {
      async () => {
      let res = await this.RefreshToken().result;
      if (res) {
        return Get(url, withToken);
      } else {
        return {data: '', error: true, redirect: true};
      }
    };
  } else {
    return {data: 'Process Error', error: true, redirect: false};
  }
});
```

In the above code, "async ()" section inside catch does not work.

This is my RefreshToken function:

```
export async function RefreshToken() {
  try {
    const ref_token = await SInfo.getItem('ref_token');
    let result = await instance
      .post(
        '/refresh_token/',
        qs.stringify({
          refresh: ref_token,
        }),
      )
      .then(({data}) => {
        if (!data.error) {
          SInfo.setItem('token', data.token.access, {});
          SInfo.setItem('ref_token', data.token.refresh, {});
          return {result: true, token: data.token.access};
        } else {
          return {result: false, token: ''};
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        return { result: false, token: '' };
      });
  }
}
```

I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: You are just defining a function without giving it a name. Give it a name and then call it after the definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is something like this:

```
let result = await instance
      .get(url)
      .then(({data}) => {
        if (data.error) {
          return {data: data.message, error: true, redirect: false};
        }
        return {data: data.data, error: false, redirect: false};
      })
      .catch(err => {
        if (err.response.status === 401) {
          const refreshToken = async () => {
            let res = await this.RefreshToken().result;
            if (res) {
              return Get(url, withToken);
            } else {
              return {data: '', error: true, redirect: true};
            }
          };
          refreshToken();
        } else {
          return {data: 'Process Error', error: true, redirect: false};
        }
      });
```

OR I think the better solution is:

```
let result = await instance
      .get(url)
      .then(({data}) => {
        if (data.error) {
          return {data: data.message, error: true, redirect: false};
        }
        return {data: data.data, error: false, redirect: false};
      })
      .catch(async (err) => {
        if (err.response.status === 401) {
          let res = await this.RefreshToken().result;
          if (res) {
            return Get(url, withToken);
          } else {
            return {data: '', error: true, redirect: true};
          }
        } else {
          return {data: 'Process Error', error: true, redirect: false};
        }
      });
```